# Socket send message only, could not receive message from server

Tags: c#, sockets

I was confused with my socket code, I want to receive the message from the client, and then send it back to client, but now I could only receive the message from the client, and failed to send it back. So how can I change my code to achieve it?

Here my server site code:

```
Socket MyClientSocket = (Socket)clientSocket;
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        int receiveNumber = MyClientSocket.Receive(result);
        message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result, 0, receiveNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("receive from{0}message{1}", 
            MyClientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), message);
        MyClientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        MyClientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        MyClientSocket.Close();
        break;
    }
}
```

Client side code:

```
Main()
    {IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("10.10.3.101");
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ip, 8885));
            Console.WriteLine("Connect success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return;
        }
        int receiveLength = clientSocket.Receive(result);
        Console.WriteLine("Receive from server{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result, 0, receiveLength));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                string message = "client send message for help " + DateTime.Now;
                clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                clientSocket.Close();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

many thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you're receiving in client code.

Comment: Be careful not to assume that Receive will read an entire "message". TCP has no messages. Receive can read any amount starting with one byte at a time.